# How can I keep checkboxes and text on the same line on mobile devices?

Tags: css, responsive-design

How can I make the text after the checkbox stay the same on an iPhone/iPad or any other mobile device?

As requested the HTML

```
<input class="sf-input-checkbox" value="film-en-tv"
name="_sft_feesttype[]" id="sf-input-58f5ef0e0b857a1a5c8674157bbb464f"
type="checkbox">
```

When I view my site on a mobile device, the text next to the checkbox "slides" under the checkbox.

Something like this:

```
X
  Text-checkbox
```

I would like to have it stay the way it looks on the computer. Like this:

```
X Text-checkbox
```

Also I wouldn't mind if it ends up looking like this:

```
X Text-
  checkbox
```

It just has to be aligned correctly...

I have tried to make the text smaller, but I can only go so far until the text is unreadable.

Does anyone here know a good solution?

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We need to see the text that is wrapping to a new line as well, @Steggie

Comment: have you solve the problem? I meet the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

see the answer for reference:

[css - How to make  and  appear on the same line on an HTML form? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23530316/8257973)

I use this method like below:

```html
<div class="cbWithText">
    <div style=float: left">
       <imput type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
       <div>Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.cbWithText {
    @media (min-width: 500px) {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```