# Input and Label elements in Html are not in the same line

Tags: html

I am new to html

I intend to create a section like this

[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVLqV.png)

This is the code I wrote for it

```
<div>
            <div style="margin: 20px;">
                {% if g.VM.MajorVersionDict.values() %}
                    <label for="versionId">Major Version</label>
                    <select id = "versionId" name="versionId" form="uploadTemplateForm">
                        {% for majorversionname ,majorversion in g.VM.MajorVersionDict.iteritems() %}
                            <option value = {{ majorversion ['id']}}>Version - {{ majorversionname }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}    
                    </select>
                {% endif %}    
            </div>
            <div style="margin: 20px;">
                <form id = "uploadTemplateForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div style = " width: 300px;">
                        <label for="file" 
                        style = "display: inline-block;width: 140px;text-align: left;">
                        File</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br /> <br /> 
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" id = "Button" value="Upload Template">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

However my section looks like this

[Observed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USDeP.png)

What should I do to get the desired section

Comment: I'd say that `<input type="file" name="file" id="file">` is behaving like a `block` element. Can you check this in your browser's development console?

Comment: Can you elaborate, in the console it does look like a separte section

Comment: Your file input's width + it's label's width exceed 300px

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530064/how-to-make-label-and-input-appear-on-the-same-line-in-html-form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make <label> and <input> appear on the same line in HTML form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530064/how-to-make-label-and-input-appear-on-the-same-line-in-html-form)

Comment: @EduardoEscobar It does not matter even if I change it 600px

Comment: @sachindhoni See my answer

Comment: Yes, it matters, i'm not using any css other than the inline css in your code, and setting `<div style = " width: 600px;">` does align both, label + file input in the same line. Look for *some other css rules* that may be causing your input#file (or even its label) to be a block element.

Comment: @EduardoEscobar well I tried with the same code, unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Take a look at this http://prnt.sc/ekis73

Comment: @sachindhoni on that `<label>` remove `display:inline-block` it'll fix it guaranteed.

Comment: Tried with that but again did not work

Comment: Has it anything to do with the browser, I have used Maxthon and Browser in my Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2**

Having gone through the obvious solutions OP still has the issue of the displaced text of the label. Next suggestion is using `display:table`. See Snippet 2, it has 2 examples:

1. **Double Classes**: Declaring class twice in a stylesheet (ex. `style.css`) or block (ie. `<style>`), increases specificity.
2. **Inline Style**: Besides using `!important` using the `style` attribute has the most specificity. If this example doesn't work, then it's has to be some code not mentioned in the question.

**UPDATE 1**
Remove `display:inline-block` on the `<label>`. As an inline element, `<label>` will of course fall inline with an inline input.

At the bottom of Snippet is a copy of the `#file` and the `<form>`. This copy has that div removed and everything is still the same. Try just removing the div.

<del>The div that wraps around the `<input id='file'>` is too small, increase width to 400px.</del> In the Snippet, you'll notice that the font is the same size all around. This helps vertically align form elements to the text of labels very easy. Add this:

> ```
> input,
> ```

```
select,
label {
 font: inherit;
}
```

**SNIPPET 1**

```css
input,
select,
label {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <label for="versionId">Major Version</label>
    <select id="versionId" name="versionId" form="uploadTemplateForm">
      <option value =''>Version - </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">
    <form id="uploadTemplateForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div width='600'>
        <label for="file">File</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <br/><br/>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="submit" id="Button" value="Upload Template">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div style="margin: 20px;">
  <form id="uploadTemplateForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="file" style='inline-block;width:140px;'>File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <br/><br/>


    <div>
      <input type="submit" id="Button" value="Upload Template">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```css
input,
select,
label {
  font: inherit;
}

.fileTable.fileTable {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.fileRow.fileRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.fileCell.fileCell {
  display: table-cell;
}

span.fileCell {
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<p>Double Classes</p>
<div class='fileTable'>
  <div class='fileRow'>
    <label for="file" class='fileCell'>File</label>
    <span class='fileCell'></span>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class='fileCell'>
  </div>
</div>
<div>

  <hr>

  <p>Inline Style</p>
  <div style='display:table;table-layout:fixed'>
    <div style='display:table-row'>
      <label for="file" style='display:table-cell'>File</label>
      <span style='display:table-cell;width:140px;'></span>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style='display:table-cell;'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Hey when I try in my code with both the methods you mentioned I still get the same issue. I know it is working beautifully here