# Contact Form 7 - CSS Tricks for Text & Field Width?

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I made a Contact Form 7 on my Wordpress website: http://ppcdigitalblack.com/contact/

I want it to include: full name*, email address*, message*, and budget dropdown list (not required)

I want full name and email address in centered field boxes that each take up half the space. I also want the font to be Lato and blue... For some reason "your full name" is gray!!

I tried all the tricks from this blog post but no luck:
https://deliciousthemes.com/contact-form-7-fields-columns/

So I'm wondering if there's a CSS trick for these two things, or if you guys have a trusted plug-in to format Contact Form 7 that works well with Uncode.

This is the code I have for the contact form, attempting to manipulate the font:

```
.contactform {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lato';
color: #777777;
}
```

This is the code I have for the width of the form, which actually gave me a more prefered form width. I'd just love to center the form fields at least, but ideally get Email and Name on the same line!

```
.wpcf7-form {
max-width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Appreciate any thoughts or advice!

Comment: Ref: [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530064/how-to-make-label-and-input-appear-on-the-same-line-in-html-form)] to this link

Comment: Quick guess on the font color... you have a closing `</p>` tag after the "Your Full Name" section with no apparent opening tag. Your other sections are fully wrapped with `p` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you.

(*For some reason "your full name" is grey!!*) -  This is because other labels are raped inside `<p>` and this label is not if you can apple the same to this then its ok. or you can just use this style.

```
form .contactform>label{
 color: #007ec7;
}
```

For using `font-family: 'Lato';` you better do the following -

Attach a font family URL in the `<head>`if you don't have yet -

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and you can apply as following below -

```
   form .contactform {
     text-align: center;
     color: #777777;
     font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 400;
    }
```

For centre align the `<input>` you can use -

```
form .contactform input[type="text"],form .contactform input[type="email"]{
         margin: 9px auto 0 !important;
    }
```

Hope this was helpful. IF there is anything else feel free to ask. :)

Comment: This worked!!! :D :D :D The <p> tag made the "full name" the same as everything else, and the input trick centered all the fields on my form!!

Comment: Be **very** cautious [using !Important](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used). Use [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) where possible.

Comment: @JonP yes you are right, I forget to mention that. Use `!important` only if your style is not applying properly. I added that because you contact form 7 default style may overight our style that why, so check it and then use it. :)